# css transition effect for border

Tags: css

hi all am using css3 transition effect here am trying to use it for border style my css

```
.round{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50px;
    border:5px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#f00;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition:all 0.5s ease 0s
}
.round:hover{
    border-style:dotted;
    border-color:#666;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

while hover the round i need to change the border-style but its not working in moz browsers i need to change the border-style by rotated way.

here my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/herzb/24/)

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/herzb/27/

```
border-style:dotted;
border-color:#666;
background-color:#ccc;
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
      transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has an open bug for this.

[Dotted/dashed border-radiused corners are rendered as solid](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721)

Notice that if you remove the border-radius property - the transition works.

So it really has nothing to do with the transition, but rather the inability for firefox to display a dotted round border.

Proof:Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herzb/30/) in firefox.

```
.round{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50px;
    border:5px dotted #ccc;
    margin:45px auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

-You won't see a dotted border.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do it.**
Unless using some border-image trick.

You use a border-radius, that makes the dots so close that will not be visible any more.

[Example with a smaller radius](http://jsfiddle.net/herzb/31/)

```
.round{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:20px;
    border:5px solid #ccc;
    margin:45px auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#f00;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.round:hover{
    border: 5px dotted #666 !important;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```